# After creating a CNAME should I rrname the GitHub repository

Tags: github, github-pages

Once created a respository named: name.github.io then added a CNAME would I be able to rename the repository without it breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DNS are pointed to github and your CNAME file is ok, it will not break. You will just have to wait for the changes to replicate in Github architecture.

**But**, you will be changing from a **user/organization** site to a **project** site. That mean that your site will have to be in a `gh-pages` branch.

You also will have to add an empty `.nojekyll` file at root to instruct Github pages not to process your site as a Jekyll site. This is important if you have `.` or `_` prefixed files or folders.